# How to dynamically move an element on a page in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This could potentially be a very basic question, but I'm trying to figure out how to move a div when a user clicks a button. In my case, I want a white bar at the bottom of a page to move downwards when a user clicks the button.

```
const [movepos, setMovepos] = useState("0")

    return (
        <>
        <div style={{
            position: "absolute",
            width: "100%",
            height: "60px",
            bottom: {movepos},
            zIndex: "10000000000",
            boxShadow: "box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px",
            backgroundColor: "white"
            }} className="media-player-bar"></div>
        <button onClick={() => setMovepos(movepos==="0" ? "-60px" : "0")}className="test-button">Click me</button>
        </>
    )
```

When setting 0 or -60px for bottom it's in the right position, but when I do it this way it just positions it at the top and the button does nothing. Is there another way of achieving what I want, or am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by *When setting 0 or -60px for bottom it's in the right position, but when I do it this way it just positions it at the top and the button does nothing.*?

Comment: Like setting bottom to those values will position the white bar at the bottom and below the bottom correctly. For some reason, doing it the way I’m doing it positions it at the top of the screen, and clicking the button, even though it changes the state, doesn’t change the position of the white bar

Comment: please explain a bit more what exactly you want to happen? for me the bar is moving when replicating it.

Comment: Really? So when you click the button the bar moves either below the screen or right at the bottom? That’s the intended behavior

Comment: check this sandbox out: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-5619c5?file=/index.js for me the bar moves up and down from 0 (bottom) to -60px (bottom)

Comment: Oh, seems to work on my project too. I'm gonna copy this solution. Any idea why mine isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to get the wanted result, i will show two of them here:

1. make your parent element 'position: relative', and then create a state for the 'top' style like this: `const [style, setStyle] = useState('top: 0px')`
   add click for the button like this: `<button onClick={() => setStyle('top: '100px')/>Click me</button>`. now pass the style to your bar element: `<YourBar style={style}/>`

this will move the element but can break the UI's page. so you will have to play with it a bit, maybe making your element `position: absolute;`

2. have two same elements and render only one of them when needed like this:
   create a state for the element flag: `const [showTop, setShowTop] = useState(true);`

and do like this: `

```html
<div>
  <button onClick={() => setTop(false)}>Click Me</button>
  {showTop && <YourBar />}
  ...
  {!showTop && <YourBar />
</div>`
```

by that you can make sure it will be positioned in right place and wont break UI.

worth mentioning, by removing an element from DOM, it will remove its height too and page will go top the same amount as the element that was removed.
if you wish to keep the height of the element, use css for visability/opacity or wrap your bar with a div and set the height you want and just hide the bar itself inside it.